# Watch pending transactions with ethjs.js

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, metamask, javascript

I am trying to use ethjs.js to listen to pending transactions, but nothing really worked. Does anyone have a working example fetching pending transactions with ethjs.js?

I have tried the following:

https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#ethnewpendingtransactionfilter

https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#ethfilter

Thanks!

Comment: Using Web3.js 1.0 instead, you can take advantage of the new `web3.eth.subscribe` function to create a WebSocket to listen for new pending txs: [Using Web3.js 1.0 Subscribe and Infura WebSockets to Visualize Ethereum Transactions](http://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/using-web3-js-1-0-subscribe-and-infura-websockets-to-visualize-ethereum-transactions/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the transaction hash you can use [ethjs-query](https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs-query). ethjs-query supports all Ethereum specified RPC methods.

```
 eth.getTransactionByHash(tHash)
     .then((result) => {
        alert(result['blockHash']);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
     });
```